# Trying to load a list that I saved to a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a script that outputs some lists to a text file, but how do I get python to load the text file when I run the script again? Code and example of text file below

````
dates = []
rpay = 10.1

while True:
    x = input("How many hours did you work today?: ")
    if x == "":
        break # exit the loop
    try:
        x = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Not a valid number. Try again.")
        continue
    hours.append(x)
    print(hours)
    a = input("Enter the month: ")
    b = input("Enter the day: ")
    c = input("Enter the year: ")
    print(a + "/" + b + "/" + c)
    dates.append(a + "/" + b + "/" + c)

thours = sum(hours)
pay = thours * rpay

print(f"You have worked {thours} hours")
print(f"You have made approximately ${pay:.2f}")

with open("hours.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(hours))
    output.write("""
""")
    output.write(str(dates))```

[3.0, 3.0]
['6/6/2020', '6/7/2020']
````

Comment: can you mention what values exaclty text file contains?

Comment: https://www.pythoncentral.io/reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python/ This webpage shows how to read text files

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for tasks like this, I would do the following:

Create a load method:

```
def load_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
         # Do whatever here
         content = f.readlines()
     return content
```

Then a save method:

```
 def save_to_file(filename, newContent):
      # save stuff here, I use append mode
      # you can also write oldContent + newContent as well
      with open(filename, 'a') as f:
           f.write(newContent)
```

If you want to make sure the file exists before loading:

```
try:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        f.read()
 except FileNotFoundError:
     # Do whatever here, create the file for example
     open(filename, 'a').close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard like JSON.

```
import json

...


with open("hours.txt", "w") as output:
    json.dump({'hours': hours, 'dates': dates}, output)
```

Later, when you want to read it back in

```
with open("hours.txt") as input:
    d = json.load(input)

hours = d['hours']
dates = d['dates']
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use built in module, [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle

with open("hours.txt", "wb") as output: # Here is where we write the lists into the txt file
    pickle.dump([hours, dates], output)

with open("hours.txt", "rb") as output: # Here is where we extract the information dumped into the txt file
    hours, dates = pickle.load(output)
```